# Is there any way to dump both HTML data and Graph data into a pdf?

Tags: java, javascript, html, graph, pdf-generation

On googling,I have found some **graph creation software's** like **amcharts,fusion charts,** etc. and **PDF creation software's** like **iText** etc which only creates graphs and writes to pdf respectively. Amcharts has an option of exporting to PDF as it exports only graph data but not html data. But my web application has both HTML data(tables,text in  tags) and graphs. I have to **write both html content and graph data to a single PDF file** using **javascript** or **Java** .Is there any way to do this.I need to generate a graph from the data in the table and write both table and the created graph to PDF. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that converting HTML to PDF is a simple task. It is because HTML and PDF structures are very different. You need some engine (or library if you want) to render/print HTML file into PDF. Then HTML file can contain anything (text, images, specially layouted elements to looks like a graph, etc.) and some engine could render it if it is good enough.

For HTML to PDF Java library you can see this thread [A java library for converting xml/html to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685395/a-java-library-for-converting-xml-html-to-pdf)

For HTML to PDF JavaScript library you can see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029132/javascript-pdf-generator-library

PS: Some version of amcharts works with flash only. It is impossible render into PDF using library. I recommend you to use something else for example [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), it si awesome JavaScript library for data visualization (like interactive charts).